# i have unfortunately deleted Root CA certificate of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

i have unfortunately deleted Root CA certificate of Jmeter..again running Test Script Recorder  showing message of CA certificate but it is not generating. Stop and start the application but the certificate is not generating. what to do to re-generate the ceritificate

Answer (score 2):

To generate a new *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt*, I removed the following from my bin folder:

```
 1. ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt (As per the question, this is already done)
 2. ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr 
 3. proxyserver.jks
```

After deleting these files, I press *Start* on my *Test Script Recorder* and see a new *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt* appear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter so I would recommend raising it via [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

In the mean time you can work it around as follows:

1. "Tell" JMeter to create its certificate in the different folder by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   proxy.cert.directory=c:/temp
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - it will generate certificate in `c:\temp` folder (make sure the folder exists)
4. Optional. You can copy the certificate to JMeter's "bin" folder and remove the aforementioned line from the *user.properties* file to revert the change just in case. Again, JMeter restart will be required afterwards
5. Re-import the new certificate into your browser/mobile device/whatever.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)